# Error - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulk-operations

I am learning PL/SQL. I have written the procedure below  using cursor and nested table to display employee names.

```
create or replace procedure
  employees_data
is
  cursor c1 is select * from employees;
  type empl_tbl is table of c1%rowtype;
  emp_data empl_tbl;
begin
  open c1; 
    LOOP
    fetch c1 bulk collect into emp_data limit 100;
    exit when sql%notfound;
    for i in 1..emp_data.last
      loop
      dbms_output.put_line ('employee name is : ' || to_char(emp_data(i).first_name));
    end loop;
    end loop;
    close c1;
end employees_data;
```

It compilesd without any errors. When I am executing the procedure, I am able to display all the employees names. But, the below error is thrown before displaying data. Can anyone please help me out of this?

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
exec employees_data()
Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "HR.EMPLOYEES_DATA", line 12
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output suggests you have not enabled DBMS_OUTPUT.  With `set serveroutput on` it becomes obvious that the error is thrown once all the employees have been processed (I added a row count to the display):

```
#100:employee name is : Douglas
#1:employee name is : Jennifer
#2:employee name is : Michael
#3:employee name is : Pat
#4:employee name is : Susan
#5:employee name is : Hermann
#6:employee name is : Shelley
#7:employee name is : William
BEGIN employees_data; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "HR.EMPLOYEES_DATA", line 12
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

So, why is this happening?  It's because you're using the wrong test after the FETCH.  `SQL%NOTFOUND` is a test for SQL statements embedded in PL/SQL.  A FETCH from an Explicit Cursor is not a SQL operation.

`SQL%NOTFOUND` is never true after a FETCH, which means the EXIT WHEN condition is never met.  Hence, the program continues to loop after all the records have been fetched.  The program hurled `ORA-06502` because `emp_data.last` is null after all the records have been fetched, so the LOOP test blows up.

The best solution is to test for the number of rows returned into the array:

```
fetch c1 bulk collect into emp_data limit 100;
exit when emp_data.count()=0;
```

With this one change your procedure will run:

```
#100:employee name is : Douglas
#1:employee name is : Jennifer
#2:employee name is : Michael
#3:employee name is : Pat
#4:employee name is : Susan
#5:employee name is : Hermann
#6:employee name is : Shelley
#7:employee name is : William

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Note that you should not use `exit when c1%notfound;` .  Although that is correct syntax for testing whether an Explicit Cursor returns a result, its behaviour is different (and non-intuitive) with bulk operations.  Then, the test is only true when the FETCH returns *the exact number of rows specified in the LIMIT clause*.  In your scenario it means you lose the last seven records:

```
#98employee name is : Kevin
#99employee name is : Donald
#100employee name is : Douglas

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Incidentally, casting FIRST_DATE is unnecessary because (assuming you are using the standard HR schema) it's already a string.  We need to use `to_char()` for things like numbers or dates, so we can control the formatting.

Comment: Hi Sir, Thank you very much for your help. I have used exit emp_data.count=0; There is no error thrown as previous.

Comment: Apologies. As I am new, it took time for me to understand how to accept it as helpful. One more question - Even when I used exit when sql%notfound;, I got complete data - 107 records. Could you please help me in understanding this.

Comment: I have amended my question to explain why testing for `sql%notfound` causes the procedure to hurl.  I hope you now can understand why it happens.  Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Now I understood the reason behind this error. Thank you once again. :)